# 2 websites hosted in different servers (different hosts) but 1 domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, dns

I have a Rails website hosted on Heroku.

I want to create a Wordpress website hosted on Godaddy.

The Rails website has specific data and has special functionality, about 40 pages. I want to have the Wordpress website on the same domain (NOT 2 different subdomains) so I can add articles and use existing WP functionality.

I can't do it in a different subdomain because it would be the equivalent of having a completely different website.

I do not want to code a CMS in Rails, that's why I want to use Wordpress. And I don't want to code PHP in a WP site to grab data from the Rails app. Any of these 2 options seem like I would be doing a lot of work, when I could just save myself weeks worth of work if I could just make the 2 sites play together under the same domain.

Is there a way to point the 1 domain to these 2 different websites? If so, how would I go about it? I've been searching online but haven't found a good reference.

Comment: https://parterburn.medium.com/wordpress-inside-a-ruby-on-rails-app-c324fbf39ad8 this might work, but havent gone through it

Comment: @rubyprince i went over this article, but my concern is the last release of the rack-reverse-proxy gem was over 5 years ago

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you're able to set up a reverse proxy or with [Cloudflare Page Rules](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/forward-subfolder-requests-to-different-server-using-page-rules/18324).  Unfortunately, it looks like Cloudflare's functionality is only available to Enterprise users.